# Trying to access facebook graph api via angular js http get returns error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use the code below to get user links via facebook graph api. But it does not work.

```
$http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='+response.authResponse.accessToken).success(function(data) {

                alert(data);

            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert(data+status+headers+config);
                });
```

Comment: The url I'm using is this:https://graph.facebook.com/me/links?access_token='+response.authResponse.accessToken

Comment: What is coming back in the error callback? That will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: nothing at all. It is empty

Comment: This could be due to cross domain issue. Have you tried to use JSONP. See documentation for Angular $http service.